# ListView onitemclick is not working

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a ListView containing a checkbox, an imageview, two textviews and a button. The problem is after adding the checkbox and the button the onitemclick event of the ListView is not responding. Will anybody suggest a work around for the problem?

Comment: If you show us your layout and your code we can try to catch the problem...

Comment: show your code, then only we know where you have done mistake, and can edit that code to solve your problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can set both `android:focusable` and `android:focusableInTouchMode` attributes of checkbox to `false` and `onItemClick` of the list will be called. But you'll have to call `CheckBox#toggle()` yourself in `onItemClick`.

Answer (score 0):

Add an onlick listner to the view. or the checkbox and handle it manually.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `checkbox` in your `listview` then it consumes your click action and your check action will be performed.

You can put click listener over textview, imageview or button. you also need to handle checkbox.